# How to find the closest time value to a given time value in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, datetime, closest

Say that I have a time value given, for example: `2012-03-28_15:10:00` 
and then I have a sting that stores multiple time values:

```
2012-03-28_14:00:00
2012-03-28_14:10:00
2012-03-28_14:20:00
2012-03-28_14:30:00
2012-03-28_14:40:00
2012-03-28_14:50:00
2012-03-28_15:00:00
2012-03-28_15:05:00
2012-03-28_15:20:00
2012-03-28_15:30:00
```

I want to find the time value in the string that is the closest to the original time value.
Does anyone know how this can be done in matlab?

Comment: `2012-03-28_15:10:00` is a char array? What about the list, is that a char matrix?

Comment: @Divakar Yes sorry, 2012-03-28_15:10:00 is a char array and the list is a char matrix.

Comment: I would do ´min(abs(t-t0))´, where ´t0´ is the one you want to find. If your time vectors are strings you should convert them first to a numerical format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

```
data1 = '2012-03-28_15:10:00'
data2 = [
'2012-03-28_14:00:00'
'2012-03-28_14:10:00'
'2012-03-28_14:20:00'
'2012-03-28_14:30:00'
'2012-03-28_14:40:00'
'2012-03-28_14:50:00'
'2012-03-28_15:00:00'
'2012-03-28_15:05:00'
'2012-03-28_15:20:00']

[~,ind1] = min(abs(datenum(data2)-datenum(data1)));
closest_time = data2(ind1,:)
```

**Output**

```
closest_time =

2012-03-28_15:05:00
```

**Extended Part:** If you have many dates, as a char matrix too and to be compared to the list, then using a `bsxfun` approach might be a better solution, as it avoids loops. This is shown below -

**Code**

```
data1 = [
'2012-03-28_14:02:00'
'2012-03-28_14:11:00'
'2012-03-28_14:23:00'
'2012-03-28_14:32:00']

data2 = [
'2012-03-28_14:00:00'
'2012-03-28_14:10:00'
'2012-03-28_14:20:00'
'2012-03-28_14:30:00'
'2012-03-28_14:40:00'
'2012-03-28_14:50:00'
'2012-03-28_15:00:00'
'2012-03-28_15:05:00'
'2012-03-28_15:08:00']

[~,ind1] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,datenum(data2),datenum(data1)')));
closest_time = data2(ind1,:)
```

**Output**

```
closest_time =

2012-03-28_14:00:00
2012-03-28_14:10:00
2012-03-28_14:20:00
2012-03-28_14:30:00
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using bsxfun instead of datenum(data2)-datenum(data1)?

Comment: @remus You are right! `bsxfun` is an over-kill for this? :)

Comment: @user3366536 Check out the `Extended Part` in the answer on why and where `bsxfun` might be "fun" :)

Comment: @user3366536 Also it seems you haven't accepted some of your previous questions, including this one (if this has answered your question). Stackoverflow states this - `Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally..`. You may read more on this here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer